# Improved unarmed strike damage bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, fighter

My character is a level 1 fighter with improved unarmed strike and I just wanted to know if that makes his damage 1D6 rather than 1D3 because I was told that it does but everywhere I've looked all it says in the description is that it makes it so you're never unarmed. Just want to know if his unarmed attacks will be d3 or d6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Improved Unarmed Strike makes it so unarmed attacks count as “armed,” so that they threaten attacks of opportunity and they do not provoke attacks of opportunity themselves. It also eliminates the −4 penalty on dealing lethal damage with unarmed strikes.

It does not in any way improve the *amount* of damage that you do. That is a class feature of the monk;<sup>1</sup> the monk gains Improved Unarmed Strike as a part of the same class feature, but Improved Unarmed Strike is only a **part** of that feature. It *also*, in addition to granting Improved Unarmed Strike, improves the damage, which Improved Unarmed Strike on its own does not.

1. <sup>Note that I state that improved unarmed damage is a class feature of the monk; it is, but monks are not the *only* class that gets it, and there are even non-class ways of doing it. I do not wish to imply that this is *exclusively* a monk thing.</sup>